# VirtualBox Shared folder problems on Fedora guest

Tags: fedora, virtualbox, network-shares

I install vbox guest additions on Fedora for using Linux guest as server and my Windows 7 host for working. So, directory on my Windows (c:\web) mapped to Linux /web and my Apache server serve from this directory. I working on Windows and changing and renaming files, that causes errors on guest.

Some times I has something like 'ls: cannot access Environment.PHP: No such file or directory'

```
[root@web application]# ls -l
ls: cannot access _Environment.PHP: No such file or directory
total 28
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 5325 Nov 21 03:01 Bootstrap.PHP
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Nov 21 02:52 configs
?????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ? _Environment.PHP
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  943 Nov 21 02:32 Environment.temp.PHP
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 4096 Nov 20 13:52 forms
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 1458 Nov 21 13:04 Init.PHP
...
```

Also I made a little test on PHP. I create file with check file_exists(). Then I make test file and has true. Then I remove file and has true again :\
I check local folder and test was passed (true, false).

I can't found what a problem. I tried to reinstall vboxadd, recreate shared folder. Mount it from /etc/fstab, by mount -t vboxsf, by automount. And always has same issue.
If I change file contents all works as expected. But if remove/add/rename files I has errors with ls: cannot access or with PHP can't determine removed file or not.

Please, where I can found error? I think problem in vboxsf file system, but where.

For info:
guest - Fedora 16 (upgraded by yum)
host - Windows 7
vm - VirtualBox 4.1.6
vbox additions updated on guest and on version 4.1.6

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and found that my fstab wasn't auto mounting for some reason. So I tried this approach instead and it worked fine:

1. Create a directory to mount into (if you haven't already): `mkdir -p /mnt/www`
2. Edit your rc.local file: `nano /etc/rc.local`
3. Append the following line and save: `mount.vboxsf -w -o fmode=0777,dmode=0777 Your_SF_Share_Name /mnt/www`

Reboot and it should mount with the correct permissions.